# Determining if pointer-to-const points to const object?

Tags: c++, c++20

Is there anyway to determine if a pointer-to-const points to a const object?

```
bool is_const_object(const int* p) {
    return ???;
}

int main() {
    int x = 42;
    const int y = 43;
    assert(!is_const_object(&x));
    assert(is_const_object(&y));
}
```

Comment: No there isn't, unfortunately. C++ does not work this way. You have to provide two separate overloads, one for const and one for non-const, and then see which one gets called.

Comment: Modifying a const object within its lifetime is still UB. So no, there is no way in standard C++ to check that.

Comment: If `p`'s type is a deduced template argument, you can use [`std::is_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const) to find out if the argument provided was a pointer-to-const or not. In the case of `is_const_object(&x)` and `is_const_object(&y)` you would get the right result, but it can't tell you the `const`ness of the pointed object in all cases.

Comment: If you want to know whether the type of the pointer passed to `is_const_object` is *pointer-to-const-something*, that's easy. If you want to know whether the pointed-to object was actually originally declared `const`, that's impossible. Consider: `int x = 42; const int* p = &x;` In this case, what would you expect `is_const_object(p)` to return?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: false.  x is not a const object

Comment: Then I'm reasonably sure it cannot be done.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a way to do this for arbitrary types (maybe for some exotic template metaprogrammed type)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't a way.  C++ does not store runtime dynamic information about something being const.  C++ does not know statically within the function if the data is really const or not.

There are a few cases where it can be done with limitations.

1. You could add your own dynamic runtime information to every const instance.
2. You could hack the loading of your executable and detect items by segment in memory.
3. You could carefully write your code to be constexpr if the pointer is to a constexpr global variable and detect that.
4. You could write a template function that takes a `T*` and detect if it is const or not.

None of these do what you are asking to do, but they do things adjacent to what you are asking to do that may fix your real problem.

Comment: Yeah, I expected as much.  I guess the implementation discards whether or not an object is const during translation.  A new compiler extension would be required to store the information in the program I guess.

Comment: And this is exactly why `const_cast` is usually a design smell and should only be used in "emergencies": you generally have no idea whether the result is truly mutable or not.